# Nested SOQL Queries

Tags: soql

I have written the query from account record to view the profile Name for the particular user (Who have created the account record)

Which user created the account record and what is his profile name for that

Query

```
select id,JDE_ship_to_account_no__c,RecordTypeId,CreatedById where CreatedById IN (select id,name,profileid form users where id = '005b0000001XwxnAAC) from account where id = '0015E00000BHkPB'
```

But it is showing error:

> Unknown error parsing query

How can I fix this query?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to query the profile name of the user who created the account. But you want this for a particular user. If you already have the id of the particular user. Why don't you request the user instead of the accounts?

Comment: You want to query the profile name of the user who created the account @MartinLezer yes

Comment: So that's not for a particular user. You just want the profile name of the guy who created a specific account. Am I right?

Comment: In Main user, so Many internal users created the account ,I want to know the profilename of the user by the help of created account

Comment: So that's not for a particular user. You just want the profile name of the guy who created a specific account. Am I right? Yes you are right

Comment: I hope it's not related but in the subSelect the closing quote isn't there. And the FROM has a typo See : (...) ,profileid form userswhere id = '005b0000001XwxnAAC).

Comment: Checkout this link : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is a problem in your query because your `where` clause is before your `from` clause. Second, you don't need a nested query because you can query the `CreatedBy` relationship directly in your master query like this:

```
SELECT CreatedBy.Name FROM Account WHERE Id = '0015E00000BHkPB'
```

Comment: @Learninguser Additionally, remember you can traverse up a relationship up to 5 levels (e.g. `Contact.Account.Owner.Manager.Name`) and down a relationship 1 level (e.g. `SELECT Id, (SELECT Name, ContentType FROM Attachments) FROM Contact LIMIT 100`).

Comment: @Dan Jones when we use  subquery like this in which criteria where CreatedById IN (select id,name,profileid form users where id = '005b0000001XwxnAAC) in which critera

Comment: @Martin Lezer now i know the CreatedBy.Name  for user,i want his profile name how we can acheive this

Comment: As @DanJones said, you can traverse up a relantionship up to 5 levels. So if you want to have the profile name you can do: `SELECT CreatedBy.Profile.Name`

Comment: @MartinLezer after using this SELECT CreatedBy.Profile.Name i got see my question

Comment: Please don't use the same question to ask something else. This is just the console that is not able to display the right text. But it works if you use it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Write something like this!

```
[SELECT id, (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMembers) FROM GROUP WHERE Name = 'Finance' LIMIT 1]
```

Comment: Could you also explain it ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke   `SELECT id, (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMembers) FROM GROUP WHERE Name = 'Finance' LIMIT 1` Using this query we are getting data from related table with same primary key